# C#: copy range of cells from excel sheet and paste in HTML email body

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, excel, copy-paste

I have an Excel sheet. The data is pretty straight forward in a few columns and rows. 
There is some formatting done on the cells (example.. colors, bold font, etc). 
I am using c# to send email. I wish to basically copy the contents of the Excel sheet and paste it in the body of the email with the formatting maintained.

Is this even possible? Am I talking BS?

Answer (score 1):

That's not an easy one.  I mean you would have to check the style of every character in every cell!  Wouldn't it be easier to just send the excel sheet?  If you provide more information about WHY you are doing it like this we might be able to suggest some alternatives which won't be so time consuming!

Edit:

The easiest is to use the `Workbook.SendMail()` method.

The Code:

```
Excel.Workbook myWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks["Book1.xls"];`
string recipients = "ElvisPresley@gmail.com";
string subject = "No need to open the attachment, you lazy ****";
bool returnReceipt = false;    
myWorkbook.SendMail(recipients, subject, returnReceipt);
```

Note that the recipients parameter is actually typed as System.Object so that the argument passed in can be a string[] if you have multiple recipients.

Comment: i am able to generate the excel sheet, attach it to the email and send. Some users are lazy and dont want to open up their attachments. if the contents are directly in the email body, then that grabs their attention .

Comment: @bcd - There you go... That SHOULD work, although I dug it out of some VERY old code :-S

Comment: Don't you need message.body = "contents extracted from excel go here" ? I don't see how you're setting the body of the message in the above code.

Comment: My recollection is that the SendMail method sends the workbook as body within the email.  I could be wrong, I extracted it from something I wrote years ago!  If it doesn't work come back to me and I'll try to write you something!  I need to know how you are currently reading the body of the worksheet/workbook so that I can make something cut/pasteable! :)

Comment: @Vijay: i am not reading the worksheet. I am just attaching it to the email. I am using Exchange Web Services api to send emails.

Comment: @bcd have you tried my suggested solution?  If it doesn't work and you REALLY need to send it in the body of the email you're going to have to read the worksheet cell by cell.  Or you could publish the xls to a HTML file and insert the HTML file into your email.  In fact, my second idea seems to be a little more practical, although it still involves reading the excel file with some sort of 3rd party library or perhaps the Excel interop stuff (not checked that out for a while, but it was a real pain back in the day!)

Comment: @Vijay: In my code, i tried the option of saving the file to HTML, then attaching the contents of this file to the body of the email and sending the email. the mail gets sent but i see this "This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them." in the body of the email. When i open up the html file that gets saved from the code in a browser, I can see all the coloring and formating being preserved . I am using the outlook 2010 client

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that if you open the HTML file in your email you can't see it (frames issue), but if you open it from the disk then it works?

Comment: Yes..  If i open the file in browser,  it works but the same contents in the body of html doesn't work.  I suspect that it could be a html rendering problem of outlook

Comment: When you say outlook, do you mean webaccess?  I've only ever seen that error when using the webaccess of outlook... How does it behave in the client application?

Comment: in outlook 2010 client  on my local machine.. i get "This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them." message. i see this message in the body of the email. I checked the same email in Chrome as wells as IE 8. out there, i don't see the message(in the body) but the body is completely blank

Comment: Update your post with the code you are using to create and send the HTML and I'll take a look.